# App is crashing on scrolling of list

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

In my app I am displaying map and list of items. I am using google place api to fetch nearest places and showing on map as markers having name and vicinity and as well as list. Here is my code

GooglePlacesActivity.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class GooglePlacesActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    List<Place> placeList;

    ListView listView;

    PlaceAdapter mPlaceAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_places);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
                addApi(LocationServices.API).
                addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                build();

        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_actionbar);
        final EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchField);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                String value = search.getText().toString();
                StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");
                googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + 1000);
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + value);
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + API_KEY);

                GooglePlacesTask googlePlacesTask = new GooglePlacesTask();
                googlePlacesTask.execute(googlePlacesUrl.toString());

                return false;
            }
        });

        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);

        if (mMap == null){
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_google_places, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000*60);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }

    private class GooglePlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        String data;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                data = Http.read(params[0]);
                Log.d("DATA", data);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            placeList = ParseJson.parsedata(result);

            for (Place place : placeList){
                Log.d("Latitude", String.valueOf(place.getLatitude()));
                Log.d("Longitude", String.valueOf(place.getLongitude()));
                Log.d("Name", place.getName());
                Log.d("Vicinity", place.getVicinity());

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < placeList.size(); i++) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(placeList.get(i).getName())
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(placeList.get(i).getLatitude(), placeList
                                        .get(i).getLongitude()))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                        .snippet(placeList.get(i).getVicinity()));
            }
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(placeList.get(0).getLatitude(), placeList
                            .get(0).getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to
                            // Mountain View
                    .zoom(14) // Sets the zoom
                    .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            mPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(GooglePlacesActivity.this, placeList);
            mPlaceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(mPlaceAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

PlaceAdapter.java

```
package com.aquib.android.placefinder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by dell on 2/19/2015.
 */
public class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place>{

    private final List<Place> list;
    private final Context context;

    public PlaceAdapter(Context context, List<Place> list){
        super(context, R.layout.place_list, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        return view;
    }
}
```

when i scroll my list, app is crashing and generating NullPointerException.

And this error is generating

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.aquib.android.placefinder.PlaceAdapter.getView(PlaceAdapter.java:46)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5143)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3243)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3587)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3431)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5585)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5631)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographe.
```

Comment: Show us the error please...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you scrolling your list `getView()` method is getting called. Now yor view is null so its showing ANR

to overcome on this situation you should do this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //View view = null;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}
```